# Multiplying 3 different inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a great simpliciation of a checkout page I'm trying to create. I'm really out of my depth and was wondering if anyone could help:

I would like to perform the following calculation with jquery when the tickbox is active and when the drop down is selected. And to recalculate if any of the other inputs change:

(#songLength slider value) x (#tracks select value) x (#basicRate value)

and to display the result in the output field.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Song Length</h1>


    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" step="0.5" class="slider" id="songRange">
        <p>Song Length: <span id="songLength"></span></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="tracks">How many tracks?</label>
        <select id="tracks">
            <option selected value="0">How Many Tracks?</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
            <option value="6">Six</option>
            <option value="7">Seven</option>
            <option value="8">Eight</option>
            <option value="9">Nine</option>
        </select> 

    <div>   
        <input type="checkbox" id="basicDisplay" name="tuning" value="10">
        <label for="tuning">Vocal Tuning</label>
    </div>

    Tuning cost: <output name = "tuningCost"></output>

<script>

    //slider

var slider = document.getElementById("songRange");
var output = document.getElementById("songLength");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a starting point:

```js
(function($) {

  var slider = $('#songRange'),
    tracks = $('#tracks'),
    checkb = $('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    output = $('output');

  var onChange = function() {
    if (!checkb.is(':checked')) {
      output.text('')
    } else {
      var sliderVal = slider.val(),
        tracksVal = tracks.val(),
        checkbVal = checkb.val()

      output.text(sliderVal * tracksVal * checkbVal)
    }
  }

  $(document).on('input change', '#songRange', onChange);
  $(document).on('change', '#tracks', onChange);
  $(document).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', onChange);

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Song Length</h1>


  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" step="0.5" class="slider" id="songRange">
    <p>Song Length: <span id="songLength"></span></p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="tracks">How many tracks?</label>
    <select id="tracks">
      <option selected value="0">How Many Tracks?</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
      <option value="6">Six</option>
      <option value="7">Seven</option>
      <option value="8">Eight</option>
      <option value="9">Nine</option>
    </select>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="basicRdisplay the result i ate" name="tuning" value="10">
      <label for="tuning">Vocal Tuning</label>
    </div>

    Tuning cost: <output name="tuningCost"></output>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much David.